# Unable to save a float value in to a variable (float) property

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to save a floating point values (from a Float[] array) to a variable property (of type float), but I am not able to save it correctly. Everytime I want to save a new value, the variable property never accepts the new value and keep retaining the intialized value only. Here I am trying to save value,

```
CommandLineVariables.PiSenseResistor = tempFloatArray[0];
```

Where,

- CommandLineVariables is the class name
- PiSenseResistor is the variable property
- tempFloatArray is the float array from which I want to save value

I tried using single stepping and watching the variable property value, but always after the execution of the above mentioned instruction, it shows the initialized value only.

The same thing I am doing with other variable properties as well and they are working correctly. I am wondering what I am doing wrong with this saving of floating point number into variable property.

### Edited

Adding some extract of the code:

```
//variable initialization
private static float piOffsetPressure = 1.01295f;

//Property definition for the variable
    public float PiOffsetPressure
    {
        get
        {
            return piOffsetPressure;
        }
        set
        {
            piOffsetPressure = value;
        }
    }
```

```
//Copy the parameter value into its corresponding property

if (!Convert.ToBoolean(ReturnCode))
{
    CommandLineVariables.PiOffsetPressure = tempFloatArray[0];
    CommandLineVariables.PdOffsetPressure = tempFloatArray[1];
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some example code? It sounds like your property may not be set up correctly, without code though, it's hard to tell

Comment: Make sure the type is not a `Nullable<int>`

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the property? I think there might be some code there that is rejecting the value.

Comment: I have posted the code I am using, is it making sense?

Comment: The fact that the field is static and the property is not strikes me as very odd, and quite likely a bug.  Why is it set up that way?

Comment: @ Chris: Could you please tell me why its odd to use a private variable with non-private property? Is it wrong or just not a good practice?

Comment: @Asad Chris Shain is questioning that the field is static while the property is not.  That fact is not related to one being private and the other public.  That is totally normal.  Staticness has nothing to do with privateness.  Using a static backing field for a property means that all instances of the class will share the same value for that property, and changing the value for any instance will cause it to change for all instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `PiOffsetPressure`, but the property you posted is `PiSenseResistor`.  Why would setting one affect the other?

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out this thing. Actually in the proeprty I have used the wrong variable in Set {}.